# How to get 'sub' claim on access_token in client credentials grant using oidc-provider npm package

Tags: node.js, oidc-provider, node-oidc-provider

The access_token generated using oidc-provider package for client_credentials grant does not contain 'sub' claim.
As per spec: [RFC 7523 : JSON Web Token (JWT) Profile for OAuth 2.0 Client Authentication and Authorization Grants](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7523)

[Please check the image for RFC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZATpn.png)

I wanted to add 'sub' claim to the access_token for client_credentials grant and populate it with the clientId.

I tried to call 'extraAccessTokenClaims' from OidcConfiguration to add 'sub' claim, but somehow oidc-provider package is removing this claim from access_token.

Any lead to resolve this issue will be really helpful.